# GameObject.renderer deprecated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deprecated, renderer

I try this code but 
`Player.renderer.enabled = false;` doesn't exist.
Here is my code:

```
public IEnumerator RespawnPlayerCo()
{
    Instantiate(deathParticle, player.transform.position, player.transform.rotation);
    player.enabled = false;
    player.renderer.enabled = false; //error is here
    Debug.Log("Player Respawn");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnDelay);
    player.transform.position = currentCheckPoint.transform.position;
    Instantiate(respawnParticle, currentCheckPoint.transform.position, currentCheckPoint.transform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: Try `player.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;` instead.

Comment: If you are changing component's values often you should consider storing reference to it in a variable    in awake or start method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-renderer.html):

> **Removed in version 5.3.5p6**
>
> Property renderer has been deprecated. Use
>   `GetComponent<Renderer>()` instead. (UnityUpgradable)